# PokéStop cooldown?

Tags: pokemon-go

How much time does it have to pass, for a PokéStop to be available again?

[Official support page](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221957688-Gather-Pok%C3%A9-Balls-Potions-Eggs) doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PokeStops will be a purple-ish color while they are cooling down, and they will restore to their original blue after their cooldown period has finished. This takes about five minutes from your last use. Other players do not affect your use cooldowns.

You may "hack" PokeStops for five minutes on end, as they do not burn out and become unavailable.

Comment: Are you sure it's five or is it a guess? Personally I was very surprised at how fast they refreshed and it felt more like two minutes but I could be wrong

Comment: @IvoBeckers I've sat there with a stopwatch a few times. It is definitely five. Unless, of course, they *very recently* changed it.

Comment: Ok, cool :) time flies when you're having fun haha

Comment: It'd be nice if their color was more obvious when they're available again. Sometimes I sit there trying to spin it for 20 seconds because "almost available blue" looks pretty much like "available blue".

Answer (score -2):

5 minutes. 40 meters.

Purple = Not-active
Blue = Active

Comment: What does the 40 meters refer to? Also there's really no need to repeat what another answer said, but putting in 0 effort.